# Text prediction (and autocorrection) while writing for Windows in several languages

Tags: text

- I would like a software where when you write some text with your physical keyboard, it'll predict the possible words to me to write. Preferably I could write the predicted word *using only my keyboard*, because pressing it with a mouse defeats the point of writing with a keyboard. (Windows default autocorrection doesn't seem to do that)
- I would also like it being in several languages and not just English. If it supports only the major languages, it'll be fine since I will need to use French and Russian.
- I would like to include custom words to replace, and it'll be cool if symbols like emojis and entire phrases could be written by replacing an abbreviation. (I don't know, maybe another service is better for that like autohotkey?)

Is this really asking too much when my phone can do that for a long time already, and PC software normally has even more functions than mobile one?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 supports text prediction:

- predicts the possible words to write
- supports several languages and not just English

[image]

Demo:

[image]

FYI: [How can I efficiently select a text prediction given by Windows' text suggestions feature?](https://superuser.com/q/1730128/116475)